# AngularJS Data not being rendered unless chrome developer tools are open

Tags: angularjs

I am having a very bizarre issue, a prototype I am working on isn't fetching data from the server unless the Chrome Developer Tools are open, If the tools are open it populates data, otherwise I would have to refresh the page to get the data to show. The snippet below shows a video of what is going on.

Any ideas?

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:0px;position:relative;padding-bottom:56.000%;"><iframe src="https://streamable.com/s/q5cex/groxxk" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden;"></iframe></div>
```

**HTML**

```
  <h1>Hello {{user.user}}</h1>
  <div id="devicesDash">
    <h2>Newest Devices</h2>
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.Device"  placeholder="Search Devices">
    <div id="devicesDisplay | filter: createdAt">
      <div ng-repeat="device in devices | filter:search | limitTo: -5 | orderBy:'time':true">
        <p>{{device._user.name}} created the device: <span class="deviceHighlight">{{device.Device}}</span> on {{device.createdAt | date:'medium'}}.</p>
      </div>
      <a ng-click="toDevices()" href="">show all devices</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller function to get devices**

```
  function getDevices(){
    BoardFactory.getDevices().then(function(res){
      console.log('fetching devices');
      $scope.devices = res;
    })
  }
```

**Factory Function to get devices**

```
   factory.getDevices = function(callback){
      return $http({
        url: '/devices',
        method: 'GET'
      }).then(function(res){
        return res.data;
      })
    }
```

Comment: By default, developer tools prevent caching. Perhaps your app is getting an empty dataset to start with and the browser is caching it and serving it for every subsequent request.

Comment: I'm confused here... you posted a code snippet that has a video of your problem?? Why not just post the actual code?  There isn't enough information in that video to begin offering anything but a guess at the problem.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and especially read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JCFord you were right, it was an issue with caching, just added a header to prevent cache in my Factory http request

Comment: in your factory $http.get("myurl",{headers:{'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}})

Answer (score 0):

in your factory $http.get("myurl",{headers:{'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}}) – Jesus Carrasco